# How to export whole data from a table in angularjs including all paginated data?

Tags: angularjs, ngtable, plunker

I am trying to export data from a `ng-table` using [ngTableExport plugin for angularjs](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table-export) but this only exports data from 1 page. I am looking for a solution which exports all data from a table (including paginated data, which also has sorting or filter data so cannot use array directly).

Below I am giving my code, somehow my [plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/hoHyeRRuuP0QGhAVBA3l?p=preview) is not working, but I am able to do a export on my local codebase.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" ng-mousedown="csv.generate()" ng-href="{{ csv.link() }}" download="myreport.csv">Export</a>
<table ng-table="tableParams" show-filter="false" class="table" export-csv="csv">
  <tr ng-repeat="item in $data" height="10px">
    <td data-title="'Date'">{{translate(item[0])}}</td>
    <td data-title="'Tasks Run Count'">{{item[1]}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

$scope.translate = function(value) {
  if (value === null || value === undefined)
    return value;
  var monthNames = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
  var myDate = new Date(value);
  return myDate.getDate() + " " + monthNames[myDate.getMonth()] + " " + myDate.getFullYear();
}

$scope.tasksRunData = [
  [1412582400000, 135, 1412582400000, 9],
  [1412586000000, 324, 1412586000000, 144],
  [1412589600000, 324, 1412589600000, 108],
  [1412593200000, 324, 1412593200000, 36],
  [1412596800000, 324, 1412596800000, 54],
  [1412600400000, 324, 1412600400000, 36],
  [1412604000000, 324, 1412604000000, 36],
  [1412607600000, 324, 1412607600000, 36],
  [1412611200000, 324, 1412611200000, 36],
  [1412614800000, 324, 1412614800000, 36],
  [1412618400000, 324, 1412618400000, 36],
  [1412622000000, 324, 1412622000000, 36],
  [1412625600000, 324, 1412625600000, 36],
  [1412629200000, 198, 1412629200000, 36],
  [1412632800000, 108, 1412632800000, 36],
  [1412636400000, 306, 1412636400000, 36],
  [1412640000000, 324, 1412640000000, 153],
  [1412643600000, 324, 1412643600000, 117],
  [1412647200000, 288, 1412647200000, 36],
  [1412650800000, 189, 1412650800000, 36],
  [1412654400000, 324, 1412654400000, 36],
  [1412658000000, 324, 1412658000000, 36],
  [1412661600000, 324, 1412661600000, 36],
  [1412665200000, 324, 1412665200000, 36],
  [1412668800000, 324, 1412668800000, 36],
  [1412672400000, 324, 1412672400000, 135],
  [1412676000000, 324, 1412676000000, 117],
  [1412679600000, 324, 1412679600000, 36],
  [1412683200000, 306, 1412683200000, 54],
  [1412686800000, 324, 1412686800000, 36],
  [1412690400000, 324, 1412690400000, 36],
  [1412694000000, 324, 1412694000000, 36],
  [1412697600000, 324, 1412697600000, 36],
  [1412701200000, 324, 1412701200000, 36],
  [1412704800000, 324, 1412704800000, 36],
  [1412708400000, 324, 1412708400000, 36],
  [1412712000000, 324, 1412712000000, 36],
  [1412715600000, 324, 1412715600000, 36],
  [1412719200000, 324, 1412719200000, 36],
  [1412722800000, 324, 1412722800000, 36],
  [1412726400000, 324, 1412726400000, 162],
  [1412730000000, 324, 1412730000000, 108],
  [1412733600000, 324, 1412733600000, 36],
  [1412737200000, 324, 1412737200000, 36],
  [1412740800000, 324, 1412740800000, 36],
  [1412744400000, 324, 1412744400000, 36],
  [1412748000000, 324, 1412748000000, 36],
  [1412751600000, 324, 1412751600000, 36],
  [1412755200000, 324, 1412755200000, 36],
  [1412758800000, 324, 1412758800000, 135],
  [1412762400000, 324, 1412762400000, 117],
  [1412766000000, 324, 1412766000000, 36],
  [1412769600000, 324, 1412769600000, 54],
  [1412773200000, 324, 1412773200000, 36],
  [1412776800000, 297, 1412776800000, 36],
  [1412780400000, 324, 1412780400000, 36],
  [1412784000000, 324, 1412784000000, 36],
  [1412787600000, 324, 1412787600000, 36],
  [1412791200000, 324, 1412791200000, 36],
  [1412794800000, 279, 1412794800000, 27],
  [1412798400000, 324, 1412798400000, 36],
  [1412802000000, 324, 1412802000000, 36],
  [1412805600000, 324, 1412805600000, 36],
  [1412809200000, 324, 1412809200000, 36],
  [1412812800000, 324, 1412812800000, 126],
  [1412816400000, 324, 1412816400000, 144],
  [1412820000000, 324, 1412820000000, 36],
  [1412823600000, 324, 1412823600000, 36],
  [1412827200000, 324, 1412827200000, 36],
  [1412830800000, 324, 1412830800000, 36],
  [1412834400000, 324, 1412834400000, 36],
  [1412838000000, 297, 1412838000000, 36],
  [1412841600000, 324, 1412841600000, 36],
  [1412845200000, 324, 1412845200000, 135],
  [1412848800000, 324, 1412848800000, 117],
  [1412852400000, 324, 1412852400000, 36],
  [1412856000000, 324, 1412856000000, 54],
  [1412859600000, 324, 1412859600000, 36],
  [1412863200000, 324, 1412863200000, 36],
  [1412866800000, 324, 1412866800000, 36],
  [1412870400000, 324, 1412870400000, 36],
  [1412874000000, 324, 1412874000000, 36],
  [1412877600000, 162, 1412877600000, 18]
];

$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
  page: 1, // show first page
  count: 10 // count per page
}, {
  total: $scope.tasksRunData.length, // length of data
  counts: [],
  getData: function($defer, params) {
    //console.log($scope.tasksRunData.length);
    params.total($scope.tasksRunData.length);
    $defer.resolve($scope.tasksRunData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
  }
});

$scope.exportPdf = function($event) {
  alert("Export to pdf click handler");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a [way here](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table-export/issues/8) by [davisford](https://github.com/davisford)

> I made some considerable changes -- namely, I needed to fix it to work with ng-table's pager. If the pager is enabled, the export plugin would only export a page of data. My fix is mostly a re-write, and it isn't perfect, but it seems to work for me.
>
> Since the plugin scrapes the HTML table data, the trick is to force the table to turn off the pager, let the browser re-render the full table, and only then parse the table (afterwards restoring the pager, to be nice and all).

forked repo [here](https://github.com/davisford/ng-table-export) with few more improvements (for some).

Other relevant solutions are also welcome.

Comment: Thank you. You save my hours.

Answer (score 0):

- Added a global variable in the ng-table

  var selectedEntries =''";
- then edit following function in ng-table

  function getData(data, params) {
  if (data == null){
  return [];
  }

  ```
              var options = angular.extend({}, defaultDataOptions, params.settings().dataOptions);

              var fData = options.applyFilter ? applyFilter(data, params) : data;
              var orderedData = options.applySort ? applySort(fData, params) : fData;
              selectedEntries = orderedData;
              return options.applyPaging ? applyPaging(orderedData, params) : orderedData;
          }
  ```
- Then add following function to the ng-table

  this.orderedData = function () {
  return selectedEntries
  };
- You can get the selected entries from the controller as following

  $scope.self.tableParams.orderedData();